# Python: Array Calculation while updating the array

Tags: python

I have a 1D Array `A` with 500,000 values. Lets say `A = [1822, 1816, 1814]`. I Also have a starting value of `45` and a divider which is `180`.
Now I need to take the first element of the array (`1822`) - starting value (`45`) = 1777. The result should be stored in a new array `B = [1777, x, x]`. Now I need to divide the first element of array `B` by `180`. The result should be stored in a new array `C = [9.8, x, x]`. Now the final array `D` starts with the starting value `45` and the second element is `45 + 9.8` so `D = [45, 54.8, x]`. Now I use the `54.8` as a new starting value. So it is `1816-54.8 = B = [1777, 1761.2, x]`. And so on until I filled all the arrays with the `500,000` values.

Comment: And what exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
a = [1822,1816,1814]
b = []
c = []
d = [45]

for index, x in enumerate(a):
    b.append(x - d[index])
    c.append(round(b[index] / 180, 1))
    d.append(d[index] + c[index])
    
for x in b:
    print(x)
    
print("")
print(f"a will be: {a}")
print(f"b will be: {b}")
print(f"c will be: {c}")
print(f"d will be: {d}")
```

The output will be:

```
1777
1761.1
1749.3

a will be: [1822, 1816, 1814]
b will be: [1777, 1761.1, 1749.3]
c will be: [9.9, 9.8, 9.7]
d will be: [45, 54.9, 64.7, 74.4]
```

**Note** that in your example the approximations were a bit wrong. I have approximated to 1 decimal place in my solution. If you want, however, you can cut the decimals and not approximate them to the right value.
In any case, I suggest you work with more decimals.

Comment: Yes i will work with more decimals. This was just as an example.. Thanks for your answer i will try to implement it now.

Comment: @Eric perfect. To add decimals in my code you can simply change the `1` in `round(b[index] / 180, 1)` to whatever decimal lenght you want.

Answer (score -1):

Not all the answer you need, but here is a way to calculate and save to another array:

```
A = [1822,1816,1814]
B = [x - 45 for x in A]
```

Then you have B = [1777, 1771, 1769]